# How to get result using stable sort using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am working on making a query which can sort the result after grouping keys in MongoDB.

Following is the example data in DB

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "code": "code",
    "groupId": "L0LV7ENT",
    "version": {
      "id": "1.0.0.0"
    },
    "status": "Done",
    "type": "main"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "code": "code",
    "groupId": "L0LV7ENT",
    "version": {
      "id": "2.0.0.0"
    },
    "status": "Done",
    "type": "main"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "code": "code",
    "groupId": "F6WJ9QP7",
    "version": {
      "id": "1.1.0.0"
    },
    "status": "Done",
    "type": "main"
  }
]
```

Here, I would like to sort the result in ascending order according to the `version.id` and to group the result according to the `groupId`.

Hence, I used the following query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "type": "main",
          "code": {
            "$in": [
              "code"
            ]
          },
          "status": {
            "$in": [
              "Done",
              "Completed"
            ]
          },
          "groupId": {
            "$in": [
              "L0LV7ENT",
              "F6WJ9QP7"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1,
      "version.id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "groupId": "$groupId"
      },
      "services": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But the result I am getting is not stable. Sometimes I see, the data with `"_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002")` coming first then `ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000") and ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")`.

It seems intermmitent. Is there any way to get a stable result?

**EDIT**

You can try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UVEZ1rlEQpA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group--aggregation-):

> $group does not order its output documents.

So you will need to sort after the group stage to have a deterministic output order.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Are you suggesting to use $group first, then $sort?
Or could you please share your solution so that I can test it out?

Comment: I'm suggesting to sort twice.  The first sort makes the order of the elements in the `services` array stable, you will need a sort after the group to make the order of the returned documents stable.

Comment: Hi, I just have checked it. But seems not working as expected. 
Could you please check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z1TmpNmAbZu)

Comment: That looks like the documents are sorted by _id value, is that not what you intended?

Comment: So as I have explained above, the question is that the document should be sorted according to 2 parameters, which are `_id` and `version.id`. and should be grouped by `groupId`, but this is what is not happening because of the intermittent behaviour as I have explained above with an example. The expected outcome should be that, the doc which is having `_id: ....00` and `_id: ...01` should come first(as they belong to the same groupId) then the doc with `_id: ...02`.

Comment: Then why did you sort by _id which contains groupId?  If you want the documents sorted by the original _id, the second sort will need to be on "services._id"